# Dates on X-axis are not plotted achartengine line graph

Tags: android, achartengine

I am stuck with this problem where I take date values from the sqlite database and try to plot them on X axis against some other values.But even after trying different solutions on SO I am unable to solve this.
Instead of my values I get random dates (1/30/1970) and the same date everywhere.

Please help me with this.

heres the code for getting the dates:

```
public Date[] getReportDates(ReportGraph reportGraph) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROW_ID, KEY_KM, KEY_FUEL_QTY, KEY_FUEL_PRICE, KEY_TOTAL_COST, KEY_MILEAGE, KEY_DATE,KEY_TANK_FULL};

        String selectQuery = "SELECT _date FROM fuel_table";
        reportCursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        int i = 0;
        int count = reportCursor.getCount();

        Date[] reportList = new Date[count];

        if(reportCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                reportList[i] = new  Date(reportCursor.getLong(0));
                i++;
            } while(reportCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        reportCursor.close();
        return reportList;

FOr graph plotting


    double[] fPrice;
    double[] fMileage;
    Date[] fDates;

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer rRenderer;

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset;
    XYSeriesRenderer priceRenderer, mileageRenderer,dateRenderer;

    public Intent getIntent(Context context)
    {

        FuelStoredInfo reportInfo =new FuelStoredInfo(context);
        reportInfo.open();
        fPrice=reportInfo.getReportData(this);
        fMileage = reportInfo.getReportMileage(this);
        fDates = reportInfo.getReportDates(this);
        reportInfo.close();




                       TimeSeries fPriceseries = new TimeSeries("Fuel prices");
                       for(int i=0;i<fDates.length;i++)
                       {
                           fPriceseries.add(fDates[i], fPrice[i]);
                       }
                       TimeSeries fMileageSeries = new TimeSeries("Mileage");
                        for(int i=0;i<fDates.length;i++)
                        {
                            fMileageSeries.add(fDates[i],fMileage[i]);
                        }


                        dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
                        dataset.addSeries(fPriceseries);
                        dataset.addSeries(fMileageSeries);
                        }
```

[image]

Comment: @Dan CAn you ahve a look at my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add date to the series in this way, may it works for you

```
long value = Math.abs(date.getTime() - 3* TimeChart.DAY);
series.add(new Date(value+ 3* TimeChart.DAY), x[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want the dates stored in my database. YOu thik it would work?

Comment: can you please tell me if my code for extracting dates from my database is right?

Comment: instead of date.getTime() put fDates[i].getTime()

Comment: and where do I add the second line? as you can see I have two values that correspond to the date. and I need the dates on x Axis as both my values are on Y axis

Comment: If I change count to long  I get an error on Date[] reportList = new Date[count]; // change count to int

Comment: Put log and check whether the date retrieved from db is correct

Comment: "reportList"  (pending) 
 [0] Date  (id=830027069584) 
 [1] Date  (id=830027069608) 
 [2] Date  (id=830027069632) 
 [3] Date  (id=830027069656) 
This is what i get

1970-01-01
1970-01-01
1970-01-01
1970-01-01

These are not what I want

Comment: Try,SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm aaa"); 
String dateString = formatter.format(fDates[i].getTime());
Log.d("test","date"+dateString);